# Does the PERC H310 Raid Controller support hard drives above 2 TB (e.g. 3 TB)?

Tags: hardware-raid

We received a new machine (Dell Precision T3600) with a PERC H310 RAID Controller.

Due to some troubles during the installation I started to read a bit about that RAID card, and I found some sources, that would state, that this card does not support 3TB.

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/w/wiki/2837.aspx

Funny enough I did not find any techsSpecs that clearly state the types of hard drives supported by this card.

We were able to configure a RAID 1 using 2 x 3TB drives. The Drives were recognized by Ubuntu and everything seams to run smooth. We did not manage to install windows so far - windows would not recognise the raid drives.

Now, as there is no clear statement available, on what has are officially supported, does anybody in this nice group now about it?

Comment: The controller obviously supports above 2TB drives if you used 3 2TB drives to form a RAID array. The configuration may be OS dependent.

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems to work without problems. I just wondered, cause the information given in the dell community tells otherwise - and there are no technical specifications that clearly state it...

Comment: `The Drives were recognized by Ubuntu `. The drives or the array? And did you boot from them ?

Answer (score 1):

The document referenced is old, so no mention of an H310 should be expected there, but >2TB support was planned for the H200 in that document, and the H310 is the replacement for the H200.

Answer (score 1):

This does support more than 3TB. The BIOS must be updated and then a UEFI installation of Windows 2008R2. We have installed 8 TB drives and this works great.